# How to send picture from canvas to server using api?

Tags: node.js, canvas

i use node js as a server. Sorry, i am very begginer in this technology. 
Im my main file index.js (i use express + bodyparser and ejs as engine) I add module for picture uploading to cloudinary:

```
    var cloudinary = require('cloudinary');
cloudinary.uploader.upload("THERE HAVE TO BE THE IMAGE", function(result) {
      console.log(result)
    });
```

Then route to page

```
app.get('/camera', function(req, res) {
  res.render('camera');
});
```

In this page i have code to work with webcamera

```
  <div class="app">
    <video id="camera-stream"></video>
    <img id="snap">
    <p id="error-message"></p>
    <div class="controls">
      <a href="#" id="take-photo" title="Take Photo"><i class="material-icons">camera_alt</i></a>
    </div>
    <canvas id="simple_sketch"></canvas>
  </div>
```

In my.js for this page I have code to take picture from web camera every 5 seconds. There is the piece witch make the photo.

```
function takeSnapshot(){
var hidden_canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
      context = hidden_canvas.getContext('2d');

  var width = video.videoWidth,
      height = video.videoHeight;

  if (width && height) {
    hidden_canvas.width = width;
    hidden_canvas.height = height;

    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
    return hidden_canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  }
}
```

**So the question, how did i can transform from canvas to image and send photo to main index.js? And after send to cloudinary**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a base64 Image of your canvas then save it as a file :
    const fs = require('fs);

```
var canvas = new Canvas(img.width, img.height);
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Write labels & values
ctx.font = '50px Arial';
ctx.fillText('Awesome!', 50, 100);
var buf = canvas.toBuffer();
fs.writeFileSync('./public/your_file.png', buf);
```

Then you can take your file created, or use the base64 with:
    ctx.toDataURL();

Comment: This answer could be improved if you made it clear the bits that are happening on the client and the bits happening on the server.

Comment: All the bits happen on the servers, don't they ?

Comment: I don’t know; sounds like he’s using a webcam, which could be anywhere.